# speech input in chrome 25 on Android

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, speech

On a PC, running chrome 25 (non beta)

shows me a microphone icon, clicking on it prompts for input.
When I stop talking, my alert call is executed. All good.
On a Galaxy Note smart phone running chrome 25 (non beta) running Android 4.04,
loading the same page does not show the microphone icon.
Also doesn't work on a Google Nexus-10 tablet running android jelly bean.

I've also tried 

which also fails to show the microphone option on android chrome 25.

Given that the Chrome 25 release touts both Android speech capabilities
and more compatibility between Android and desktop Chrome, 
I'm surprised this doesn't work. 
Anybody else tried this and gotten it to work?

Answer (score 1):

As of M25 and M26 Beta it is not implemented in Chrome for Android.

You should star this bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=112934

Also of interest is the continuous speech input API, so follow this issue https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116954

Answer (score 0):

[CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=speech%20recognition) says this functionality is available in Chrome 55 released December 7th 2016